# ggplotly stacked area plot without cumsum labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

So here's the issue. Using this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

Values1 <- rep(10, 10)
Values2 <- rep(20, 10)
X <- rep(seq(1, 10),2)
df <- data.frame(Values1=Values1, Values2=Values2)
df <- melt(df)
df2 <- data.frame(X=X, Label=df$variable, Value=df$value)

Plot <- ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=X, y=Value)) + 
  geom_area(data=df2, aes(fill=Label), position='stack')
ggplotly(Plot)
```

my label on the stacked area shows Values1+Values2 rather than the value of Values1.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `text` and `tooltip` will give you what you want:

```
Plot <- ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=X, y=Value, fill=Label, text = paste("Value:", Value))) + 
geom_area(position='stack')
ggplotly(Plot) 
ggplotly(tooltip = c("text", "x", "fill"))
```

Comment: This helps a ton. Thanks very much.